# How to empty cache for WebView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, webview

I have a Webview that must load an image! When I upload this image I see every time the same image as before, and i must reboot my app to see the new image... 
I think is a cache problem..How can I solve that??

Answer (score 6):

One quick and easy method would be to append the current time stamp onto the url whenever you load it.

So instead of loading:

```
http://www.myhost.com/myimg.jpg
```

you'd load

```
http://www.myhost.com/myimg.jpg?12345689
```

Using a cache breaker like this is a very common method in web development to force reloading of content.

I did do some quick googling and it appears clearing out NSURL's cache won't do the trick. In 10.6 the api `reloadFromOrigin:` may do the trick, but I'm not aware if this has made it's way onto the iphone yet.

**Edit:**

I found [this page](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebPreferences_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001900-SW22) in the docs.  It looks like you can use the preferences system to say whether or not to use caching.  Not tested, but that'd be something to look at.