# Android Webview - Completely Clear the Cache

Tags: android, caching, webview

I have a WebView in one of my Activities, and when it loads a webpage, the page gathers some background data from Facebook.

What I'm seeing though, is the page displayed in the application is the same on each time the app is opened and refreshed.

I've tried setting the WebView not to use cache and clear the cache and history of the WebView.

I've also followed the suggestion here: [How to empty cache for WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790254/how-to-empty-cache-for-webview)

But none of this works, does anyone have any ideas of I can overcome this problem because it is a vital part of my application.

```
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
    {
           public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
           {
               if(progress >= 100)
               {
                   mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
               }
               else
               {
                   mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
               }
           }
    });
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new SignInFBWebViewClient(mUIHandler));
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.clearHistory();
    mWebView.clearFormData();
    mWebView.clearCache(true);

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

    Time time = new Time();
    time.setToNow();

    mWebView.loadUrl(mSocialProxy.getSignInURL()+"?time="+time.format("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"));
```

So I implemented the first suggestion (Although changed the code to be recursive)

```
private void clearApplicationCache() {
    File dir = getCacheDir();

    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        try {
            ArrayList<File> stack = new ArrayList<File>();

            // Initialise the list
            File[] children = dir.listFiles();
            for (File child : children) {
                stack.add(child);
            }

            while (stack.size() > 0) {
                Log.v(TAG, LOG_START + "Clearing the stack - " + stack.size());
                File f = stack.get(stack.size() - 1);
                if (f.isDirectory() == true) {
                    boolean empty = f.delete();

                    if (empty == false) {
                        File[] files = f.listFiles();
                        if (files.length != 0) {
                            for (File tmp : files) {
                                stack.add(tmp);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        stack.remove(stack.size() - 1);
                    }
                } else {
                    f.delete();
                    stack.remove(stack.size() - 1);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, LOG_START + "Failed to clean the cache");
        }
    }
}
```

However this still hasn't changed what the page is displaying. On my desktop browser I am getting different html code to the web page produced in the WebView so I know the WebView must be caching somewhere.

On the IRC channel I was pointed to a fix to remove caching from a URL Connection but can't see how to apply it to a WebView yet.

http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/45/

If I delete my application and re-install it, I can get the webpage back up to date, i.e. a non-cached version. The main problem is the changes are made to links in the webpage, so the front end of the webpage is completely unchanged.

Comment: `mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);` did not worked ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The edited code snippet above posted by Gaunt Face contains an error in that if a directory fails to delete because one of its files cannot be deleted, the code will keep retrying in an infinite loop. I rewrote it to be truly recursive, and added a numDays parameter so you can control how old the files must be that are pruned:

```
//helper method for clearCache() , recursive
//returns number of deleted files
static int clearCacheFolder(final File dir, final int numDays) {

    int deletedFiles = 0;
    if (dir!= null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        try {
            for (File child:dir.listFiles()) {

                //first delete subdirectories recursively
                if (child.isDirectory()) {
                    deletedFiles += clearCacheFolder(child, numDays);
                }

                //then delete the files and subdirectories in this dir
                //only empty directories can be deleted, so subdirs have been done first
                if (child.lastModified() < new Date().getTime() - numDays * DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS) {
                    if (child.delete()) {
                        deletedFiles++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("Failed to clean the cache, error %s", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }
    return deletedFiles;
}

/*
 * Delete the files older than numDays days from the application cache
 * 0 means all files.
 */
public static void clearCache(final Context context, final int numDays) {
    Log.i(TAG, String.format("Starting cache prune, deleting files older than %d days", numDays));
    int numDeletedFiles = clearCacheFolder(context.getCacheDir(), numDays);
    Log.i(TAG, String.format("Cache pruning completed, %d files deleted", numDeletedFiles));
}
```

Hopefully of use to other people  :)

Comment: Great routine, saved us a lot of agony.

Comment: Can I use this code within an app to clear cache for certain app installed on my phone?

Comment: If the whole directory needs to be deleted wouldn't Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm -rf "+dirName+"\n"); be easier?

Comment: @source.rar Yes, but then you have no ability to keep files younger than x days old, which typically you want for a cache folder.

Comment: You might want to put `getTime()` into a variable outside the loop so you don't call it everytime.

Comment: Is it possible to use this code to only delete HTML files in the cache?

Answer (score 240):

I found an even elegant and simple solution to clearing cache

```
WebView obj;
obj.clearCache(true);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#clearCache%28boolean%29

I have been trying to figure out the way to clear the cache, but all we could do from the above mentioned methods was remove the local files, but it never clean the RAM.

The API clearCache, frees up the RAM used by the webview and hence mandates that the webpage be loaded again.

Comment: The best answer and I wonder why its not accepted..Kudos Akshat :)

Comment: No luck for me.  Wonder if something has changed?  I can load a WebView with google.com and the WebView still thinks I am logged in, even after clearCache(true);

Comment: @lostintranslation For that you probably want to delete cookies. Though I'm sure you found that out by now.

Comment: Need to allocate the object?
WebView obj= new WebView(this); obj.clearCache(true);
Anyway, very good for me, upvoted!

Answer (score 49):

I found the fix you were looking for:

```
context.deleteDatabase("webview.db");
context.deleteDatabase("webviewCache.db");
```

For some reason Android makes a bad cache of the url which it keeps returning by accident instead of the new data you need. Sure, you could just delete the entries from the DB but in my case I am only trying to access one URL so blowing away the whole DB is easier.

And don't worry, these DBs are just associated with your app so you aren't clearing the cache of the whole phone.

Comment: Thanks, this is an incredibly neat trick. It deserves to be more widely known.

Comment: This throws a nasty exception in honeycomb: 06-14 22:33:34.349: ERROR/SQLiteDatabase(20382): Failed to open the database. closing it.
06-14 22:33:34.349: ERROR/SQLiteDatabase(20382): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error
06-14 22:33:34.349: ERROR/SQLiteDatabase(20382):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_setLocale(Native Method)

Comment: Cheers Rafael, I would like to think this is because the original issue has been resolved in Honeycomb. Does anyone know if this is the case?

Comment: just put 2 lines in onBackpress() or back button no history remain in back stack
thanks saved lots of time.

Comment: This does not seem to clear JS cache, only HTML.. is that the case?

Answer (score 42):

To clear all the webview caches while you signOUT form your APP:

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);         
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();        
cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
```

For Lollipop and above:

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);         
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();        
cookieManager.removeAllCookies(ValueCallback);
```

Comment: save my life and day.

Comment: Works fine if you don't have access to webview in your activity. Also note that this API has been deprecated,so use the "removeAllCookies(ValueCallback)" API instead on L+ devices.

Comment: what should I replace with ValueCallBack?

Comment: @QaisarKhanBangash new ValueCallback<Boolean>() {
      atOverride
      public void onReceiveValue(Boolean value) {
        
      }
    }

Answer (score 27):

To clear cookie and cache from Webview,

```
    // Clear all the Application Cache, Web SQL Database and the HTML5 Web Storage
    WebStorage.getInstance().deleteAllData();

    // Clear all the cookies
    CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
    CookieManager.getInstance().flush();

    webView.clearCache(true);
    webView.clearFormData();
    webView.clearHistory();
    webView.clearSslPreferences();
```

Answer (score 6):

**The only solution that works for me**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
    CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
    CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should clear your applications cache which should be where your webview cache is

```
File dir = getActivity().getCacheDir();

if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
    try {
        File[] children = dir.listFiles();
        if (children.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                File[] temp = children[i].listFiles();
                for (int x = 0; x < temp.length; x++) {
                    temp[x].delete();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Cache", "failed cache clean");
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this (Changed code slightly) and still got the same results -> Explained above

Answer (score 3):

```
webView.clearCache(true)
appFormWebView.clearFormData()
appFormWebView.clearHistory()
appFormWebView.clearSslPreferences()
CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null)
CookieManager.getInstance().flush()
WebStorage.getInstance().deleteAllData()
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply using below code in Kotlin works for me

```
WebView(applicationContext).clearCache(true)
```

Answer (score 2):

Previous code has been deprecated. So, you can try this one in Kotlin base android projects:

```
CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies {  
   // Do your work here.
}
```

Comment: I use this method to solve my problem. I see many answers containing "CookieManager.getInstance().flush()". It is not needed, because flush() write cookie to database in fact. If you want to clear all db, you can try  WebStorage.getInstance().deleteAllData(); but in most cases it is not needed

Answer (score 1):

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);         
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();        
cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);    
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance(); 
cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
```

It can clear google account in my webview

Comment: CookieSyncManager is depricated

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use below method for the form data not be displayed as autopop when clicked on input fields.

```
getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear the history, simply do:

```
this.appView.clearHistory();
```

*Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html*

Answer (score 0):

```
context.deleteDatabase("webview.db");
context.deleteDatabase("webviewCache.db")
```

Did the trick

Answer (score 0):

to completely clear the cache in kotlin you can use:

```
context.cacheDir.deleteRecursively()
```

Just in case someone needs the kotlin code (: