# Caching problem with a web view activity

Tags: android

The activity launched is a webview activity.when i login first time then shows the login page but when logged on second time then the web view cache the pervious login and shows me the homepage instead it should be showing a login page again.i don't have a logout button in my web view.

```
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.myaccount:
        // intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UIBMainView.class);
        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyAccount.class);
        //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a little over the top for what you want to do, but should solve your problem:

[Android Webview - Completely Clear the Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465432/android-webview-completely-clear-the-cache)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gaunt.I m still not able to solve the problem of loading the login screen.I think the session getting stored somewhere.so do u have sometime idea on hoe to deal with session.