# I cleared WebView history but the hyperlink color still purple

Tags: android, kotlin

The history of WebView is clearing but the link I visited was still purple, not change back to the blue.

```
//kotlin code

val webView = web_view
webView.canGoBack()
webView.loadUrl("https://bing.com")
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun doUpdateVisitedHistory(view: WebView, url: String, isReload: Boolean) {
        webView.clearCache(true)
        webView.clearHistory()
    }
}
```

I am sure `webView.cleatHistory()` is available, because I cannot back to previous page.

The history has been cleared. Why the link color that I clicked still purple?

Comment: look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6089359/8187578 it should fit your needs.

Comment: I tried the solution but it not work.

Comment: Try this one then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465432/android-webview-completely-clear-the-cache

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be a Chromium bug. There is no solution unless restart the APP.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=709627