# Android webview is playing video only once

Tags: java, android, video, android-webview

I am using webview in android to play a video. The problem is that video is playing once. I have seen some answers about how to fix it, but still not working. Here's my code:

```
public class MyChromeClient extends WebChromeClient implements
    OnCompletionListener, OnErrorListener {

    private Activity _activity;
    private VideoView mCustomVideoView;

    private LinearLayout mContentView;
    private FrameLayout mCustomViewContainer;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;
    static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams COVER_SCREEN_GRAVITY_CENTER = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER);

    public MyChromeClient(Activity context) {
        super();
        _activity = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
        super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);
        if (view instanceof FrameLayout) {
            FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) view;
            if (frame.getFocusedChild() instanceof VideoView) {
                mCustomVideoView = (VideoView) frame.getFocusedChild();
                frame.removeView(mCustomVideoView);
                _activity.setContentView(mCustomVideoView);
                mCustomVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                mCustomVideoView.setOnErrorListener(this);
                mCustomVideoView.start();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onHideCustomView() {
        if (mCustomVideoView == null)
            return;
        // Hide the custom view.
        mCustomVideoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // Remove the custom view from its container.
        mCustomViewContainer.removeView(mCustomVideoView);
        mCustomVideoView = null;
        mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mCustomVideoView.stopPlayback();
        mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
        // Show the content view.
        mContentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //Intent intent = new Intent(_activity, _activity.getClass());
        //intent.setClass(_activity, _activity.getClass());
        //_activity.startActivity(intent);
        //_activity.finish();
    }

    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: where have you used your callback in showCustomView method??

Comment: Same question with answer here http://stackoverflow.com/q/8310550/1503155 . Have you checked it?

Comment: Yes I have checked it but the methode onPrepared does not exist, or maybe it is deprecated

Comment: newBee I didn't understand your question

Answer (score 0):

try this 
add this in show method

```
WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback CustomViewCallback; mCustomViewCallback = callback;
```

then in hide method...

```
mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden(); mCustomViewCallback = null; HTML5WebView.this.goBack();
```

EDIT :-

```
  public class HTML5WebView extends WebView {

    static final String LOGTAG = "HTML5WebView";

    private void init(Context context) {
        mContext = context;     
        Activity a = (Activity) mContext;

        mLayout = new FrameLayout(context);

        mBrowserFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) LayoutInflater.from(a).inflate(R.layout.custom_screen, null);
        mContentView = (FrameLayout) mBrowserFrameLayout.findViewById(R.id.main_content);
        mCustomViewContainer = (FrameLayout) mBrowserFrameLayout.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_custom_content);

        mLayout.addView(mBrowserFrameLayout, COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS);

        // Configure the webview
        WebSettings s = getSettings();
        s.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        s.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        s.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        s.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        s.setSaveFormData(true);
        s.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebChromeClient = new MyWebChromeClient();
        setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
        setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        s.setDomStorageEnabled(true); 

        mContentView.addView(this);
    }

    public HTML5WebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public HTML5WebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public HTML5WebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    public FrameLayout getLayout() {
        return mLayout;
    }

    public boolean inCustomView() {
        return (mCustomView != null);
    }

    public void hideCustomView() {
        mWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if ((mCustomView == null) && canGoBack()){
                goBack();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        private Bitmap      mDefaultVideoPoster;
        private View        mVideoProgressView;
        FrameLayout frame;

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback)
        {
            HTML5WebView.this.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            isVideoPlaying = true;
            // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
            if (mCustomView != null) {
                callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                return;
            }

            mCustomViewContainer.addView(view);
            mCustomView = view;
            frame = (FrameLayout) mCustomView;
            mCustomViewCallback = callback;
            VideoView mVideoView;
            if(frame.getFocusedChild() instanceof VideoView){
                mVideoView = (VideoView) frame.getFocusedChild();
            }
            mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onHideCustomView() {
            if (mCustomView == null)
                return;        

            // Hide the custom view.
            mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Remove the custom view from its container.
            mCustomViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
            mCustomView = null;
            mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
            mCustomViewCallback = null;

            HTML5WebView.this.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            HTML5WebView.this.goBack();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried it but still not working. What is this HTML5WebView? Is the the WebView that I am using? If it is, there's no "this". And if it is the activity that contains the webview, then there's no "goBack()" method.. Thank you for your help!

Comment: ohh sorry i forgot to mention that, its a class that extends webview, and in that class i have show and hide methods. Webview has goback method

Comment: Please check i have edited answer, this is the code i referred while adding the required functionality to project. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to offer an alternative, it may not be perfect, but from a web programming point of view, after beating my head against this for some time, the trick was to covert the video to base64 and the feed it to the source tag (jquery in my case). If it isn't in the assets folder it can't get confuse!