# Android - GoogleMap Clear Cache

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have designed one app, in that I am calling a `Fragment` which shows a map from `FragmentActivity`. But, when I retrun back to `FragmentActivity` from `Fragment` of `Map` it shows blackscreen. It loads the list after 20 to 30 seconds..

So, is there is any solution on this which will clear the map cache while returning to `FragmentActivity` from `Fragment` so that list on `FragmentActivity` will be displayed properly..?

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate: [Programmatically clearing map cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709071/programmatically-clearing-map-cache)

TL;DR - No, you can't clear the GoogleMap cache as of API v2 yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly possible to delete Map Cache

Tiles are stored in your data directory

To see it, use File Explorer

[image]

Go in your application data folder to see it:

[image]

Programmatically, there is the way to clear it:

```
context.dataDir
    ?.listFiles()
    ?.first { it.name == "app_tilesFolder" }
    ?.deleteRecursively()
```

Change the name if the cache folder change in the future

Comment: I haven't found `app_tilesFolder` on my device. What was the version of Google Maps you used?