# Delete cached files - WebView Android 4.4+

Tags: android, caching, webview, chromium

I managed to delete cached files created by WebView using:

[Clearing android cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787335/clearing-android-cache),
[Clear Application cache on exit in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977288/clear-application-cache-on-exit-in-android)

However for Android 4.4 that solution doesn't work properly, since the files are cached in:

```
/data/data/com.app.package/app_webview/
```

instead of:

```
/data/data/com.app.package/cache/
```

The above path can be obtained by the official command `getCacheDir()`.

An approach could be hard-coding the path obtained through [Get Application Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527764/get-application-directory)

However, is there any [official]/proper solution to address this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```
    private static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (String aChildren : children) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, aChildren));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // The directory is now empty so delete it
    return dir != null && dir.delete();

}

void trimCache() {

    try {
        String pathadmob = this.getFilesDir().getParent() + "/app_webview";
        File dir = new File(pathadmob);
        if (dir.isDirectory()) {
            deleteDir(dir);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also, here was generated all admob cache 4.4+, you can use a code to verify how many times the user use the app, and delete the admob cache when the user reached the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, to clear WebView cache, use this WebView API: `WebView.clearCache(true);`