# Garbage collection in HTML5 android apps?

Tags: android, html

Is there any kind of garbage collection to clean up unused resources on HTML5 apps?

I have an HTML5 app on Android that runs inside a WebView. It uses a lot of images, and in some android devices it takes so many memory that the device runs out of it.

Would it be useful to call the System.gc or it would not make any sense?

thanks

Comment: how about this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465432/android-webview-completely-clear-the-cache