# How to completely reset Android webview before load new request

Tags: android, webview

I am using **Android WebView** to load some webpages. In my case, I have to insert some JavaScript codes before loaded webpages. Just like below:

```
//enable javascript
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

//inject my js first. 
//I can't inject the js onPageStarted() or onPageFinished() because I need to make  sure the js
//is injected before html loaded.
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:MyJsCode"); 

//load HTML      
mWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com/demos/index.html");
```

The code works fine first time, but failed when run it more than one time. Because the HTML can't find my JS.

I think because the previous HTML is not clear completely, so `mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:MyJsCode")` inject MyJsCode to previous HTML instead of the new HTML.

So I thought if I could completely reset the `WebView(to clear the previous HTML)`, will solve my issue.

I tried `WebView.ClearView(), loadUrl("about:blank")`, they all doesn't work.

Anyone suggestion?

Comment: Just a question.. Are you running it on Android 4.1?

Comment: Reproduce on both Android 2.3 and 4.1.

Comment: I don't about 2.3, but I've faced a bug on Android 4.1. Whenever you execute Javascript on a WebView, the Webview just refuses to do anything until the application is restarted.. This hasn't happened on 2.3.3 or 4.0.3, so maybe your problem is different..

Comment: I believe our problem is different. You could post a new thread about your issue and I can take a look.

Comment: Actually, we fixed it by reworking our code to not need Javascript, so all is fine.. :-)

Comment: Just a suggestion to get some hint.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465432/android-webview-completely-clear-the-cache?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is no way to do this except re-new a WebView.

Answer (score 5):

Though this is a a tiny bit late, I offer the following.  Perhaps it may be helpful . . .

Your question does not specifically mention using any of the callbacks in the `WebChromeClient`, but you do mention JS, so the following may help.  In SDK level 16 and below, you can use the callbacks without specifically "clearing" them.  However, starting with SDK level 17, I observe that you must act to clear the events -- specifically `alert()`, which, of course, results in `onJSAlert()` being fired in your `WebChromeClient` if you override it.  In all the devices I have tested at SDK level 16 and below, you may blithely ignore the callback, and all will go to plan.

However, you will note that `onJSAlert`, when overridden, delivers a `JSResult` object in the last parameter, thus:

> **boolean**    onJsAlert(**WebView** view, **String** url, **String** message, **JsResult** result)

I observe that the JsResult object has two methods exposed, thus:

> *Public Methods*
>
> **final void**     cancel()
>
> > ```
> > Handle the result if the user cancelled the dialog.
> > ```
>
> **final void**     confirm()
>
> > ```
> > Handle a confirmation response from the user
> > ```

Assuming that one returns **true** in the callback (indicating that the callback consumed the onJsAlert event), and assuming that you are using SDK 16 or before, then `WebView.destroy()` will do the expected things.

I observe, however, that SDK 17 (4.2.x) seems to want some further proof that the callback did, in face, handle the event.  Failing to call `result.cancel()` or `result.confirm()`, will leave your `WebView` (or, more to the point, the `WebViewCore`) stuck permanently.  Nothing I have tried will reawaken the `WebViewCore`, and, thereafter, nothing will load in any `WebView`, **new** or otherwise.  (Attempted explanation: `WebView` is merely a wrapper class for `WebViewProvider`, which, in turn instruments a `WebViewCore` object.  It's that last fellow, `WebViewCore`, that does all the work.  Through wandering the source code, and through reflection, you can burrow your way into that object, if you are keen to do so.  `WebViewCore` is a `static`, thus, there is exactly one `WebViewCore` for the whole of your application.  Ergo, if your one-and-only WebViewCore gets stuck, no `WebView` in your application will work thereafter.  Once it is stuck waiting, for example, for a `JSResult` method to be called, it will be stuck until the application is destroyed (i.e. even pausing/resuming the app has zero effect). Even calling `destroy()` on the `WebViewCore` directly, through access gained through reflection is ineffective.  N.B. Calling `destroy()` on the `WebView` has the side-effect of calling `destroy()` on the `WebViewCore` but that, too, does nothing helpful).

So, the symptom is that

1. you create a `WebView`
2. some clever JS runs, perhaps calling *alert()*
3. you handle the *alert()* in your `onJsAlert` override method
4. you fail to call either `result.confirm()` or `result.cancel()`
5. you destroy the `WebView`
6. thereafter, no `WebView` in your application will load anything.

The good news is that if you are sure to "clear" the events in whatever callbacks you override by invoking the appropriate JsResult method, then the `WebViewCore` will not permanently stop, and your application will be happy.

Comment: Thanks so much~~I got something from your feedback~~

Comment: Glad it shed even a tiny bit of light. Perhaps upvote, if you have time.