# How to disable cache in android webview?

Tags: android, webview

In my android webview my webpage is loading even without internet because of cache, so i want to disable cache in android webview, can anyone help me how to do this?

I am using following lines in my webview, but still i am not able to disable cache.

```
     myBrowser.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
     myBrowser.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
```

Please suggest me if there are some other methods

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Webview - Completely Clear the Cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465432/android-webview-completely-clear-the-cache)

Answer (score 66):

Please add below code

```
mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

Please remove app from history task and test its working.

Comment: Works like a charm! I was having an issue with a payment gateway not updating the Amount in case user presses BACK and updates the order value. Now it works!

Comment: Can't thank you enough! Too much time wasted on this!

Comment: It seems setAppCacheEnabled is now deprecated. Does anyone know what replaced it..?

Comment: @Sho Hi, if it is still the issue, try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62354423/how-to-use-serviceworkercontroller-on-android/63491172#63491172 and here is info from javadoc: 
The Application Cache API is deprecated and this method will become a no-op on all Android versions once support is removed in Chromium. Consider using Service Workers instead. See https://web.dev/appcache-removal/ for more information.

Answer (score 35):

Just after creating your webview, before loading any pages, you can clear the cache.

`myBrowser.clearCache(true)` - the boolean indicates if you wish to delete the cached files on disk as well.

The [documentation is here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#clearCache%28boolean%29) if you wish to dig further.

Comment: I applied that without having to look for on SOF and Is correct but **unfortunately doesn't work for me** that way. Answer by @Piyush above did.

Comment: Perfect solution !

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. Even though I had the below two lines, my webview was still loading old data.

> webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
>      webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

My mistake was, i had this cache related settings after I called the loadUrl() on webview. After I moved these cache settings ahead of loadUrl(), i had everything working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

```
 webView.clearCache(true)
 webView.clearHistory()
 webView.settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE;
```

Those 3 methods before the loadUrl method worked for me. Don't forget to clear the app storage or uninstall the app completely to test for the first time.