# How we can clear url cache in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, fetch

We will do clear URL cache by using this **removeAllCachedResponses** in iOS, but in React Native how we can do and we are using **fetch**. We are unable to clear URL cache programmatically in React Native. Can anyone have a solution for this? Check here what I'm doing in Swift, how we can acheive this in React Native?

```
        URLCache.shared.diskCapacity = 0
        URLCache.shared.memoryCapacity = 0
        URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
```

Comment: Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41146572/11469794) it has full details with references.