# Android Webview signout issue

Tags: android-webview

In my webview app when I run the app for the first time and log out from a user session, close the app and then when I open the app again instead of asking user credentials I find myself already logged in. I tried clearing cookies but then it always require sign in on every restart. I only want it to ask for sign in when the user logs out from the app.

Please Help!!

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.framelayout);
    bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    bar.setMax(100);
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mywebview);
    webview.clearCache(true);
    webview.clearHistory();
    WebSettings mWebSettings = webview.getSettings();
    mWebSettings.setSaveFormData(false);




    swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);
    swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            LoadWeb();
        }
    });

   LoadWeb();

}

public  void LoadWeb(){

    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mywebview);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new HelpClient());




    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){




        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bar.setProgress(newProgress);

            setTitle("Loading....");

            if (newProgress == 100){
                frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                setTitle(view.getTitle());
            }
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
        }
    });
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webview.loadUrl(WebAddress);
    webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload(true)");

    swipe.setRefreshing(false);
    bar.setProgress(0);


}


private class HelpClient extends WebViewClient{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        frameLayout.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        swipe.setRefreshing(false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {

        try {
            webview.stopLoading();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        if (webview.canGoBack()) {
            webview.goBack();
        }

        webview.loadUrl("about:blank");
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Check your internet connection and try again.");
        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();

        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);

    }


}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        if (webview.canGoBack()){
            webview.goBack();
            return true;
        }
    }


    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31338188/9311972

Comment: @PaulChu yes I tried that. Didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Run below code before `loadUrl()`

```
WebStorage webStorage = WebStorage.getInstance();
webStorage.deleteAllData();
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
```

I test it using Gmail account

Answer (score 0):

`CookieSynManager` is now deprecated. This works for me :

```
WebStorage.getInstance().deleteAllData()
CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null)
```