# android kitkat webview cache issue

Tags: android

One day, My customer says "Webview cache seem to stack **data** area, not cache area. My device is Optimus G 4.4.2 Kitkat".

Whether cache is really accumulate in the data area, i checked my 4.4.2 device.

so, **cache was being really accumulated the data area**.

and, it does not delete the following way.

```
protected void trimCache(Context context) {
    try {
        dir = context.getCacheDir();
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            deleteDir(dir);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

protected boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        children = dir.list();
        for (String aChildren : children) {
            if (deleteDir(new File(dir, aChildren))) continue;
            return false;
        }
    }
    assert dir != null;
    return dir.delete();
}

and, Webview.clearCache() and Context.deleteDatabase("") .
```

I have two Question.

1. How can i delete cache in the **data** area?
2. if i can't delete cache in the data area, How i can turn off android webview cache.

p.s. I'm not native speaker, so my english is not enough.

Comment: Picture: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/0fVyPvG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
How can i delete cache in the data area?
```

You can take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465432/android-webview-completely-clear-the-cache) for further info as to how to delete the cache data. There is a recursive method that, that guy is using.

```
if i can't delete cache in the data area, How i can turn off android webview cache.
```

You can try using

```
     mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
     mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
```

But more importantly, just after creating your webview, before loading any pages, you can clear the cache, as mentioned in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#clearCache%28boolean%29) here.

`mWebView.clearCache(true)`

Comment: i tried raj's answer, but seem to not work. so, i decided turn off webview cache when device sdk is 19 or above.

Answer (score 0):

i am using this to clear cache from data.

```
    try {
            File cache = getCacheDir();
            File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());

            if (appDir.exists()) {
                String[] children = appDir.list();
                for (String s : children) {

                    if (!s.equals("databases") &&!s.equals("lib") && !s.equals("shared_prefs")) {

                        deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));

                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```