# do webview settings affect all webview?

Tags: android, webview, android-websettings

Having WebView, and some settings. 
The question is will these settings set on one WebView instance affect the browser of the other WebView instance, such as the browser cache, domStorage?

```
mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

What if set the settings on a webView in one activity and called activity.finish(), later in other activity instantiates new webView.

If they do get carried over, how to clear the data stored by the setting of setDomStorageEnabled(true)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is will these settings set on one WebView instance affect the browser of the other WebView instance

No. If you change the settings for one `WebView` the settings for other `WebViews` will stay the same. Ie. If you change the settings for `myWebView`, then `SomeOtherWebview` will still have the original settings.

> activity.finish(), later in other activity instantiates new webView

Your new `WebView` will be a fresh one, with the default settings.

---

Note that all `WebViews` in your app share:

- DOM (Html5) storage. Not sure how to clear this.
- Cookies. To clear, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24053236/4428462).
- Cache. To clear, do `webView.clearCache(true)`
- History. To clear, do: `webView.clearHistory()`

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3697397/4428462) for how to clear *everything*.

Answer (score 0):

Each WebView has it's own settings that you acesss with `getSettings()`