# Removing Instagram user data from WebView in Android

Tags: android, webview, fragment, instagram

I have a Webview in my android project that opens the Instagram URL in a dialog fragment. 
I want that everytime the fragment is closed to delete all cashe and information collected by the webview and when I restart it the webview will start fresh with no user information. 
I have tried EVERYTHING - nothing works and all documentations about it are very old and not helpful. 
thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465432/android-webview-completely-clear-the-cache

Comment: I tried this : 

WebView obj;
obj.clearCache(true);

and nothing happends - I put it on the onDestroy() method of the dialog fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: 
after 2 days of heavy digging into this issue I came up with the idea to set the Instagram log-off URL within the onDestroy() method and it magiclly worked. If anyone has any use of it, the url for loggin off is 
https://instagram.com/accounts/logout