# Does webview in apps cache the pages?

Tags: java, android, iphone, objective-c, ios

I have developed a web application that runs on Android and iOS. Does the webview cache the pages in some way? I am making changes to the html at the server, but it changes randomly, it does not always change. Is this correct behaviour? I thought it should look at the HTTP header and see that it has been modified.

Comment: Have a look at [this][1], It might help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790254/how-to-empty-cache-for-webview

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's definitely caching happening in UIWebView's on iOS. I wasn't able to find any reasonable solution (headers, etc.) when I came across the problem. We ended up renaming files server-side in order to trick it into de-caching things.